# ASP.NET Web-Api working local but not after deploy on IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My Web-Api project works just fine on my local machine but after i deployed it to my file system and copied it to a windows server 2008 - IIS7, i get this exception when trying to access the RESTful-Service.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   HappyOrder.WebApi.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() +0

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12601933
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618980
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458597
```

This occured after I installed Nuget-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors, first it did not even work locally but then i managed to get it working with the Nuget-Package Manager Commando "Update-Package".

Comment: You should probably check the version of .Net installed in server and also ASP.Net version. This is definitely framework setting in IIS App pool

Comment: How did you deploy it? Are you sure your `bin` directory contains listed assemblies?

Comment: @Thanigainathan: .Net version on server is 4.5.2, asp.net targets 4.5, asp.net version is 5.2.3.0

Comment: @Kamo: yes, there are assemblies listed in the bin directory
I deployed it this way:
1.) Publish RESTful-Service via vs2015
2.) via Remote-Desktop file upload to server, first deleting the old files and than replacing them with the new published ones

Answer (score 0):

Please reinstall ASP.Net in server with this command

aspnet_regiis.exe -i

This will set ASP.net right and make it work

Comment: What command should I use, if I do not want to change all ASP.NET versions of the published servers?
I am not alone working on this machine.

Comment: We can try alternative options. Have made copy local true for this dll ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply install the package:

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.2.3
```

or the version with which you are getting the error.